# WPF Window DataContext error "invalid column name"

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, ef-code-first

Trynig to set DataContext to WPF Window I am using CodeFirst and here is the code

```
    public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "FullName")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "FullNameRequired")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public double Salary { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Job { get; set; }

}

public class EmployeeVM
{
    SDBContext db = new SDBContext();

    public List<Employee> Employees;

    public EmployeeVM()
    {
        this.Employees= db.Employees.ToList();
    }
}
```

added the ViewModel to the window datacontext

```
 xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:Project_Test.ViewModels"

<Window.DataContext>
    <VM:EmployeeVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

But I get the error "invalid column name Job"

and I tried binding 'Employees' Collection to DataGrid but it didn't work

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"
```

Done that in codebehind and it works fine

```
SDBContext db = new SDBContext();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DG_Employees.ItemsSource = db.Employees.ToList();
}
```

**Update**

I deleted the attribute 'Job' and got another error:
"the model backing the context has changed since the database was created. consider using code first"

Answer (score 0):

For your first approach to work, your `Employees` has to be property, not field, like this:

```
public class EmployeeVM
{
    SDBContext db = new SDBContext();

    public List<Employee> Employees {get;set;}

    public EmployeeVM()
    {
        this.Employees= db.Employees.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then when you bind ItemsSource to your Employees it should work.

But.

If you plan loading Employees from database somewhere except costructor, your `EmployeeVM` [should implement INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx) and `Employees` property should raise `PropertyChanged` event on change, so your Viewmodel should look like:

```
public class EmployeeVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    SDBContext db = new SDBContext();

    private List<Employee> _employees;
    public List<Employee> Employees
    {
        get { return _employees; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _employees)) return;
            _employees = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Employees");
        }
    }

    public EmployeeVM()
    {
        this.Employees = db.Employees.ToList();
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then, every time you do `this.Employees = /..something../` your bound DataGrid should see ItemsSource changed.

But even more, if you plan to let user add/remove `Employees` from DataGrid or in some other way modify `Employees` collection , you should change `Employees` property type from `List<Employee>` to `ObservableCollection<Employee>`, and then your View (e.g. DataGrid) should get events whenever new Employee will be removed or added to `Employees` collection.

And there's more, if you plan changing Employee's properties like `FullName` etc and want these changes to be noticed by view (e.g. DataGrid to update corresponding cell after Eployee's `FullName` was changed) your Employee class, in turn, should implement INotifyPropertyChanged too - but even better, you let alone Employee which is a part of Model and loaded from database and create separate viewmodel for Employee class.

I have to add, if your task is only to load Employees from database once on ViewModel construction, get them to View, read-only, no editions, updates or deletions, you could omit all the hassle above, but I think that's a rare scenario.